# Facebook FQL limited friends issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using facebook FQL to get the friends list 
I am using this query

```
"select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())";SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1"
```

Its working fine but it returns me only few friends like 15 to 20
I need all my friends in responce
Any idae?
Thanks

Comment: `is_app_user = 1` means that you only want your friends that are using the app

Comment: if i set the velue is_app_user=0 then there is no data for friends list

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using v2.0 of the Graph API. Therefore, you only get the friends which also use the app of which the requesting user access token was issued

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

If your app was set up before April 30th 2014, you can specify that you explicitly want to use v1.0, which will give you all friends. This will only work until April 30th, 2015. If the app was created later, there's no possibility to get all friends.